# How to check the Sun Directory Server version?

Tags: ldap, solaris, solaris-10, sunos

How to get LDAP Server (Sun DS) Information in Sun OS 5.10

```
SunOS hostname 5.10 Generic_144488-06 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240
```

Specifically

1. Server Type
2. Server Version
3. Protocol

Using the command below:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port-s base -b '' '(&)' vendorName vendorVersion
```

Produces:

```
ldap_search: Protocol error   
ldap_search: additional info: Bad search filter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the query below:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port -b "" -s base -D "cn=somecn" "(objectclass=*)" vendorversion objectClass isGlobalCatalogReady vendorname
```

Result:

```
version: 1
dn:
vendorversion: Sun Java(TM) System Directory Server/5.2_Patch_4
objectClass: top
vendorname: Sun Microsystems, Inc
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -h hostname -b "" -s base -D cn=admin,dc=yourdomain,dc=com -W "(objectclass=*)" vendorversion objectClass isGlobalCatalogReady vendorname
```

[Source](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Determine%20LDAP%20Server%20Vendor)

Comment: with some tweaks it worked, ldapsearch -h host -p port -b "" -s base -D "cn=mycn" "(objectclass=*)" vendorversion objectClass isGlobalCatalogReady vendorname